# I cannot get an MBED ticker within a class to call a member method

Tags: c++, c++11, mbed, nucleo

I wrote the following MBED-based C++ program as an experiment for a more detailed project I am working on for my Nucleoboard Microcontroller:

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut greenLed(PA_5);

#include "mbed.h"
class TimedLED
{
    public:
        TimedLED()
        {
            Ticker t;
            t.attach_us(this, &TimedLED::flip, 1000000);
        }

        void flip(void)
        {
           static int count = 0;
           greenLed.write(count%2); //-- toggle greenLed
           count++;
        }
};

int main()
{
    TimedLED flash;
    while (1);
}
```

All the references I looked at seemed to indicate that t.attach_us(this, &TimedLED::flip, 1000000) should call the method, 'flip' every second and so cause the LED to toggle on and off. This is not happening, however. I cannot see what the problem is. I hope someone can help me clear this up.

I am getting the following warning message indicating that this format is deprecated, but the link to the documentation was broken, so I couldn't get more details:

```
Function "mbed::Ticker::attach_us(T *, M, us_timestamp_t) [with T=TimedLED, M=void(TimedLED::*)()]" (declared at /extras/mbed_fd96258d940d/drivers/Ticker.h:122) was declared "deprecated" "t.attach_us(this, &TimedLED::flip, 1000000);"
```

Even if it is deprecated, it still should work, shouldn't it? Also, presumably if the deprecation message is correct, there is a newer way to do the same thing. I can't find reference to an alternative method though anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `Ticker t;` in your constructor on the stack, when the constructor exits it will clear the object, and thus the code will not run.

Declare the variable in your class, and it'll run as expected:

```
class TimedLED
{
    public:
        TimedLED()
        {
            t.attach(callback(this, &TimedLED::flip), 1.0f);
        }

        void flip(void)
        {
            static int count = 0;
            greenLed.write(count%2); //-- toggle greenLed
            count++;
        }

    private:
        Ticker t;
};
```

Also note the change in the constructor, this is the prefered (non-deprecated) way to attach callbacks in mbed OS 5.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I am learning C++ at the same time as mbed, so it is easy for me to miss important points like the fact that t had to be declared as a data member if it were to have scope throughout the class.